# Select particular element from dropdown Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, automation, automated-tests

I have a web-element which on click produces a dropdown, I am able to click on web-element and see see all the elements using the code.

```
By mySelector = By.xpath("//li[contains(@class,'ant-select-dropdown-menu-item')]");
List<WebElement> myElements = driver.findElements(mySelector);
        for (WebElement e : myElements) {
            System.out.println(e.getAttribute("outerHTML"));
        }
```

Also

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[text() = '"
                    + user.getHomeLocation() + "']")).isDisplayed();
```

**returns true**

But I am not able to click the desired value.I want to click **Westminster**

```html
<li unselectable="unselectable" class="ant-select-dropdown-menu-item-active ant-select-dropdown-menu-item" role="menuitem" aria-selected="false" style="-moz-user-select: none;">Select</li>
<li unselectable="unselectable" class="ant-select-dropdown-menu-item" role="menuitem" aria-selected="false" style="-moz-user-select: none;">Basking Ridge</li>
<li unselectable="unselectable" class="ant-select-dropdown-menu-item" role="menuitem" aria-selected="false" style="-moz-user-select: none;">Highlands Ranch</li>
<li unselectable="unselectable" class="ant-select-dropdown-menu-item" role="menuitem" aria-selected="false" style="-moz-user-select: none;">Westminster</li>
```

Comment: Your code trial `to click on web-element`? Additionally instead of the output by `outerHTML` update the question with the relevant HTML of the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Try to add one more 'contains' to xpath locator with needed item:

```
//li[contains(@class,'ant-select-dropdown-menu-item')][contains(.,'Westminster')]
```